# How can I limit Enumerable.Range to use count of the last index only and not exceed from it? - Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Each time I used this as a datasource for the repeater, eventually it will display page numbers which are out of index in the pagination that I made for gridview. Do you guys have an idea to limit this enumerable.range in accordance with the gridview.pagecount? I want to display 10 page numbers per index click only. So here is the code

```
protected void Repeater_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater Repeater = (Repeater)sender;
    Repeater.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(GridView1.PageIndex + 1, 10);
    Repeater.DataBind();
}
```

My Gridview has 21 page count all in all, but I want to display 10 page numbers per numbers click.

for example here, I clicked 2, it will display 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 or 2-11, this works if you really have a 10 page count in the gridview, but what if I don't have a 10 page count? what if I have like 3 page count then I put 10 there in enumerable.range?

That is what I am currently facing on, and I hope you guys help me with the dilemma I am currently dealing with.

and also if I clicked 21 which is the last page count, it will display 21-30 which is not in the gridview1.pageindex anymore.

**Update**

This is the image of my problem...

Image: [image: Check]

Also this is what I did in my code for now

```
  protected void Repeater_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Repeater Repeater = (Repeater)sender;

            Repeater.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(GridView1.PageIndex + 1, GridView1.PageCount); // 10
            Repeater.DataBind();

        }
```

Comment: Can you take either 10 or whatever number is left? Like `int numberToTake = new[] { GridView1.PageCount - GridView1.PageIndex, 10}.Max();`

Comment: You should put logic to check the current pageindex of grid view and pagesize  before deciding the range of numbers to assign to repeater

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, can you atleast help me on how will I implement that in repeater_load?

Comment: @LyoshaKorogoda, whatever number is left, so if I am on page number 21 the   Repeater.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(GridView1.PageIndex + 1, 10); should be modified to be like (pagenumber 11 - 21) something like that

Comment: because if there is no limit or in relation to the pageindex, when I click to (pagenumber 21 it will display this... (pagenumber 21-30)

Comment: I'm not sure what your specific question is. What is it you cannot do? The math? Access the variable? Something else entirely?

Comment: `Range should be modified to be like...` I simply suggest that you calculate the number of pages left till the end (e.g. `gridView.PageCount - gridView.PageIndex`) and pass either that or 10 -- whichever is smaller -- as a second argument (i.e. the number of elements to take) to the `.Range`. PS: Yeah, it should be `.Min()` in my previous comment.

Comment: @LyoshaKorogoda for now what I am trying to do is adding if statements

Comment: @nvoigt I added some details on my question, I hope you got the point now sir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Range` expects two arguments: the starting number and the number of elements to take.

If I understood you right, and you want to split your pages into batches of 10, you can calculate these values dynamically --

```
int currentPage = GridView1.PageIndex;
int batchSize = new[] { GridView1.PageCount - currentPage, 10 }.Min();

Repeater.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(currentPage, batchSize);
```

Comment: thanks alot, thought I still have problems with this code, I got the point already on how to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Page Count of the GridView to get the correct number of items in the Repeater like this.

```
Repeater1.DataSource = new string[GridView1.PageCount];
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

ASPX

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.ItemIndex > 0 ? " - " : "" %>
        <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: sorry, but this is not what I am asking for

Comment: I think it is. By using `PageCount` as the size of the array bound to the Repeater will make sure the items will never go above the page count.

Comment: but sir, how will I apply it to the enumerable range?

Comment: Why? you don't need to use `Enumerable.Range` at all.

Comment: as you can see on the added details on top, I need to change the range of the page numbers / repeater items with every gridview.pageindex selected on the repeater items which in this case is the page numbers for pagination

Comment: thank you for helping out, I am satisfied with lyosha's answer, since I got the idea when lyosha's posted the answer